# How to Retrieve Systems Properties from Azure Mobile Services .Net Backend

Tags: xamarin, azure-mobile-services

How can I retrieve the System Properties of "__createdAT" and "__updatedAT" from an Azure Mobile Service Table (.Net Backend). I see that these values exist on the Azure SQL Server.

This is my backing Model Class

```
public class Customer : EntityData
    {
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string CardUid { get; set; }

    }
```

And I can confirm that the columns are created at the Azure Mobile Services backing SQL Backend
[image: Azure Mobile Service System Properties CreatedAT]

And here is my Xamarin Android model class

```
public class Customer
    {
        public string id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "customerName")]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "customerEmail")]
        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "phoneNumber")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "cardUid")]
        public string CardUid { get; set; }

        [CreatedAt]
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

        [UpdatedAt]
        public DateTime LastTransactionDate { get; set; }

    }
```

However, this does not return the values, here is what it returns to the Xamarin.Android client

[image: Azure Mobile Services Created AT Image]

Even the web Try it out does not return the CreatedAT and UpdatedAT column, how can I return these columns to the clients.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the client SDK you need to specify that you want the system properties returned (they are not by default).

In C# you would do something like this:

```
    customerTable = myAzClient.GetTable<Customer>;
    customerTable.SystemProperties = MobileServiceSystemProperties.CreatedAt | MobileServiceSystemProperties.UpdatedAt;
var customers = await customerTable.ReadAsync();
```

You can see more in Carlos' [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/12/02/accessing-optimistic-concurrency-features-in-azure-mobile-services-client-sdks.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming you CreatedAt and UpdatedAt  Properies in your client side DTO classes.

```
public class Customer
{
   ....

    [CreatedAt]
    public DateTime CreatedAt{ get; set; }

    [UpdatedAt]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt{ get; set; }

}
```

This worked for me the last time

Comment: Thank you, I renamed the properties and still AMS is returning those properties as simple a DateTime field with no value. Take a look https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15447938/Azure_CreatedAt.JPG